# Is it possible to debug Intellij IDEA itself?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I know that only the Community edition of Intellij IDEA is open source so I'm specifically asking about this version. My question is, is it possible to install plugins in IDEA and then debug the plugins' code? Or is it possible to debug Intellij itself while **working in it**?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is a good idea to debug IJ by itself. If you'll stop at any break point (with all threads suspending) you will not be able to work with IJ because it's frozen.
You can attach the remote debugger to another instance if you start IJ with parameters that can be found in the `remote` run/debug configuration.
From my understanding, the easiest way to attach a debug to IJ is to create a simple dumb plugin and start in the debug mode.